# PHP: connect X.pdf to X.png in a chosen directory

Tags: php, directory

I am looking for a PHP script that connects *.PDF to *.PNG files in a directory. Due to lack of PHP knowledge, I only know how to do this manually in HTML. Could PHP do this for me automatically by connecting A.pdf with A.png, B.pdf with B.png, C.pdf with C.png and so on? Then all I need to be able doing is to change the folder name in PHP.

```
<div><a href="FOLDER/A.pdf"><img src="FOLDER/A.png"></a></div>
<div><a href="FOLDER/B.pdf"><img src="FOLDER/B.png"></a></div>
<div><a href="FOLDER/C.pdf"><img src="FOLDER/C.png"></a></div>
```

etcetera...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood this correctly, but the code below will get all .pdf files from a directory and return the HTML for each .pdf file.  This will also check to see if the .png exists, but will not echo anything if it does not exist.

```
// get all .pdf files from directory
$directory = "directory/";
$files = glob($directory."*.{[pP][dD][fF]}", GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($files as $item) {
    // get pathinfo to get the filename
    $fileInfo = pathinfo($item);
    $fileName = $fileInfo['filename'];
    // check if the .png exists
    if (file_exists($directory.$fileName.".png")) {
        // echo
        echo "<div><a href='".$directory.$fileName.".pdf'><img src='".$directory.$fileName.".png'></a></div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I just changed the $directory to "./Folder". That is the directory where my files are stored. However, at the moment nothing is happening. Is there a code error?

For clarification: The png contains the book cover of the pdf-file. So A.png is the cover of A.pdf, B.png is the cover of B.pdf. So, the website shows these bookcovers on which users can click to download them as pdf. Does this help?

Comment: I updated my answer and it should work now, forgot to put the directory variable where I was checking to see if the png exists. 

Makes sense now. I think this code should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Yes! Great. Thanks.